# Google Analytics - Track Fake Pageview

Tags: google-analytics

I have been trying for a while and I cant seem to get it to work. I am just wondering how to track a fake pageview in google analytics, I have a link that leads to an external site, and I want to track it to a fake page when the user clicks on it. Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function track(someurl){
_gaq.push(['trackPageview', someurl]);
   }
 </script>

 <a onclick="track('/financeclick.html');" target="_blank" href="http://www.external-link.net/"><img width="75px" class="right left-marg" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/financing2.png" /></a>
```

Can Anyone give me a hand with this one?

Comment: what you did is right, whats problem in it ? i think you may not know where to look for it ? these previews will available on left site in content tab in GA

Answer (score 0):

`<a onclick="recordOutboundLink(link);" href="#">link</a>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function recordOutboundLink(link) {
try {
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', link]);
setTimeout('document.location = "' + link.href + '"', 100)
}catch(err){}
}
</script>
```

Btw, you should use trackEvent instead of pageviews